# Lower correlation in sub-group than in main-group

Tags: correlation, python, pearson-r

**Variable 1:** Points in the NBA in Year 1;
**Variable 2:** Points in the NBA in Year 2;
**Objective:** Calculate the year-to-year correlation coefficient

Let's say the correlation coefficient for the entire dataset is 0.8.

However, when I divide the dataset into sub-groups based on position, the correlation coefficients are much lower (between 0.4 and 0.7). I still have a few hundred observations per position, so I don't think it's a sample size issue.

Why is that? What conclusions can I draw from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is absolutely not surprising, since (presumably) points scored depend heavily on position, which is your grouping variable. Players in one position may have a lower correlation between points they score in the two years, but they are still likely to score higher or lower than players in another position *in both years*.

Here is an illustration of some random data. Note how each color's points are pretty much uncorrelated, but the clusters follow an upward slope, which indicates the overall propensity for certain positions to score more or fewer points. Perhaps a plot like this makes sense to visualize your data, too.

[image: NBA]

R code:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(1)
back <- mvrnorm(100,c(1,1),diag(rep(1,2)))
middle <- mvrnorm(100,c(2,2),diag(rep(1,2)))
forward <- mvrnorm(100,c(3,3),diag(rep(1,2)))
all <- rbind(back,middle,forward)

cor(back)
cor(middle)
cor(forward)
cor(all)

plot(back,xlim=range(all),ylim=range(all),pch=19,col=1,
    xlab="Year 1",ylab="Year 2",las=1,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
points(middle,pch=19,col=2)
points(forward,pch=19,col=3)
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the reasoning. The chart does help and I agree that it depends heavily on position. However, I still don't quite understand why the correlation within each position is lower. If we assume that centers score less, the correlation could still be high - just within a smaller range. What am I missing? Is it related to this piece about range restrictions? https://www.bmj.com/content/342/bmj.d556##

Comment: The key thing is that centers' scores (may) show little correlation between years. That *overall* scores show higher correlation is an artifact of the influence of position. The best unit of analysis is players at comparable positions. If you look at the correlation between height and weight for men only and women only, you will again get lower correlations than if you pooled men and women, because men are systematically both taller and heavier.

Comment: I still don't get it. Men are heavier and taller -- agreed. But why is the correlation lower if we isolate men or women? Within their boundaries, the correlation could still be similarly high or not? 

Regardless of that, would the interpretation then be that there is a high correlation (because we focus on the correlations of the entire group), but that the strength of the correlation differs for positions or gender respectively?

Comment: It *could* be that the correlation within groups is still high. The point is that correlations within groups can be low, but correlations across all groups can be high if the groups differ systematically. You could even have strong *negative* correlations within each group, but a *positive* correlation in the pooled dataset, which is precisely [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

Comment: Okay thanks. would the interpretation then be that, in general, there is a high correlation (because we focus on the correlations of the entire group), but that the strength of the correlation differs for positions or gender respectively?

Comment: That is one way of looking at it. I think the other way around is more helpful: focusing on correlations within clearly defined subpopulations. In the end, what the right lens is to look at your problem depends on the subject. If you do astronomy, your lens should be a telescope; if you do cell biology, it should be a microscope.